# Simplify json_decode result

Tags: php, json

It's simple function , request data by cURL and get JSON. I just want to use data in JSON but why it's a lot stdclass object. How can I simplify this code ?

```
<?php
function movieRequest()
{
    $url = "http://api.com/content/movies?format=json";
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $headers[] = "Content-type: application/json"; 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}

$data = movieRequest();
$data = (array) json_decode($data);
print_r(get_object_vars(get_object_vars($data['categories'])['Access-Channel'])['category']); //Need this data but it still has stdClass Object. 
?>
```

It's too much '`get_object_vars`'. Any better way to get data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the second parameter of [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and have a associative array as result:

```
$data = movieRequest();
$data = json_decode($data, true );
print_r( $data['categories']['Access-Channel']['category'] );
```

From the documentation:

> **assoc**
>
> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.